# roxygen2: @noRd tag has no effect in presence of the @rdname tag in documenting internal functions

Tags: r, roxygen2

I am using **roxygen2** package to document my package. [As suggested by Hadley Wickham in section 7.8](https://style.tidyverse.org/documentation.html),

> Internal functions should be documented with `#'` comments as per usual. Use the @noRd tag to prevent `Rd` files from being generated.

Often, I have internal functions in one R file and thus use the @rdname tag. Yet if I use the @noRd tag it has no effect.

For instance, if you `roxygenize()` this file called "iloveAnimals", inside a package:

```
#' @title Cats
#' @name iloveAnimals
#'
#' @description The following logical functions check if you love animals
#'
#' @param loveCats Logical; TRUE if you love Cats
#' @details
#'  loveCats: do you love cats
#' @rdname iloveAnimals
ilovecats <- function(loveCats){
  if(loveCats){
    print("you love cats")
  } else{
      print("you hate cats")
    }
}

#' @param loveBirds logical; TRUE if you love birds.
#' @details
#'  loveBirds: Do you love birds?
#' @rdname iloveAnimals
ilovebirds  <- function(loveBirds){
  if(loveBirds){
    print("you love birds")
  } else{
    print("you hate birds")
  }
}

#' @noRd
```

yields, within a package,

```
roxygen2::roxygenize()
Writing NAMESPACE
Writing NAMESPACE
Writing iloveAnimals.Rd
```

This is surprising as the `Rd` file should not be written. The `Rd` file is written as if the @noRd tag has no effect. If @rdname is not used, the @noRd tag works and the `Rd` file is not written. There are two easy solutions:

1. Comment out the internal functions or
2. have one internal function per file to avoid using @rdname tag.

However, these solutions violate the spirit of **roxygen2**.

Comment: This is crossreferenced in the r-oxygen2 github bug report page (issue #1141): https://github.com/r-lib/roxygen2/issues/1141

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please **roxygen2** github page for the answer to this question. Thanks, @gaborcsardi.

https://github.com/r-lib/roxygen2/issues/1141#issuecomment-660612297
(copied from there):

> Roxygen blocks and roxygen tags apply to the expression after them, so you'll need to put the @noRd in front of the expression you don't want the .Rd file for. Maybe you'll also have to remove @rdname, I don't know, but it us useless with @noRd, anyway:

```
#' @title Cats
#' @name iloveAnimals
#'
#' @description The following logical functions check if you love animals
#'
#' @param loveCats Logical; TRUE if you love Cats
#' @details
#'  loveCats: do you love cats
#' @noRd

ilovecats <- function(loveCats){
  if(loveCats){
    print("you love cats")
  } else{
      print("you hate cats")
    }
}
```

> See this for an alternative that only leaves the internal function out of the index: https://blog.r-hub.io/2019/12/12/internal-functions/#how-to-document-internal-functions